# change the size of Fragment tabs using ViewPager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I want to change the size of fragment tabs.
is there any way?? that we can change the size of fragment tabs created using **View Pager** and **Fragments** ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. You need to implement Material design classes to resize it.
Material design tabs are new and best solution for tabs.
classes are provided by google.

[Material Design Tabs](https://github.com/google/iosched/tree/master/android/src/main/java/com/google/samples/apps/iosched/ui/widget)

From given link download both following classes,

SlidingTabLayout.java

SlidingTabStrip.java

and you have to do same as ViewPager.

need to implement following in mainActivity.xml
where you can customize the size of tabs.

```
<com.example.android.tabs.SlidingTabLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="35dp" //Size of tabs.
        android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
        android:id="@+id/tabs"/>
```

and then add this tabs to ViewPager,

```
mPager.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));
    mTabs.setViewPager(mPager);
```

You can change the size of tabs the way want. Hope it helps :)